# Eye expressions and gestures

Tags: word-request

We sometimes use our eye(s) to draw someone's attention towards something being done or spoken to show as if we don't like it either, or as a taunt, saying:

**'Ugh! Just look at this man! What he is saying is!'**

What is the particular verb for this action?
To give an optic gesture???

Comment: There are many, such as **"rolled their eyes (in disgust)", "raised an eyebrow", "squeezed their eyes"** etc. The rule is to just describe the movement.

Comment: @  Bella Swan I think there must be a particular word used as a verb for this particular action. Like there is a verb 'wink' used as a private signal to somebody, or to show something is a joke

Answer (score 1):

You would just say **"he/she gestured towards the man with his/her eyes"**. But there isn't a verb that combines all of these words into one.

Like some of the ideas mentioned in earlier comments, we would use a phrase:

- focused his/her gaze towards the man
- raised an eyebrow towards the man

Answer (score 1):

The precise gesture may be culturally dependent, but I think "rolled his eyes" could describe this.

> [roll one's eyes](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/roll+(one%27s)+eyes)
>   To turn one's eyes upward or around in a circle, usually as an expression of exasperation, annoyance, impatience, or disdain.